# Can't able to create the build in Xcode 11.2.1 with error "Role is Admin, but at least Admin is required"

Tags: swift, xcode, build, ipa

I try to create build and it's show message that "Role is member, at least admin is required to create the build" .

now my account got updated and its showing following error ..

[image]

I think this is a kind of bug .... 
I restart the Xcode and try again but it still showing the same error as before ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting the `Xcode` not work for me ... Restarting the Mac worked.